# Call a function with parameters in SQLalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to call a PostGreSQL function from python using SQLAlchemy: the function looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_all(ID1 VARCHAR(20), ID2 VARCHAR(20),
trans_00 VARCHAR(1000), trans_1G VARCHAR(1000), trans_1S VARCHAR(1000),
cont VARCHAR(1000), fr VARCHAR(1000), hasmod VARCHAR(1), act_ch FLOAT,
cat_ch VARCHAR(2), count INT RETURNS void AS $$
...
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In python I tried:

```
_upload={'ID1':linesplit[0], 'ID2':linesplit[1], 'trans_00':linesplit[2],
'trans_1G':linesplit[3], 'trans_1S':linesplit[4],
'cont':linesplit[5], 'fr':linesplit[6], 'hasmod':linesplit[7],
'act_ch':linesplit[8], 'cat_ch':linesplit[9], 'count':linesplit[10]}

a=self.connection.execute(sqlalchemy.text('select
insert_all(:ID1, :ID2, :trans_00, :trans_1G, :trans_1S, :cont, :fr,
:hasmod, :act_ch, :cat_ch, :count) from dual'), _upload)
```

The error I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: A value is required for bind parameter '1' (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/cd3x)
```

Do you think that would it be possible to do a batch insert (instead of using `_upload={...}` use `_upload.append({...})` and insert more rows at once)?

Comment: Thank you for spotting that out. I corrected it, but not this was causing the problem.

Comment: what is inside of `...` in your function definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use [func](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) method from sqlalchemy. It workd for me:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

a = session.execute(func.your_schema.insert_all(*_upload.values()))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works well, but would it be possible to do a batch insert as well? E.g. having _upload not as dictionary but a list of dictionaries? Something similar to bulk insert.