# Merge JSON in a mysql column using sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, json, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I want to merge json data distributed over multiple rows in a mysql column via python sqlalchemy library. I was planning to use `json_merge_preserve` but unable to use over an entire column.

I used following code:

`select(func.json_merge_preserve(db.mytable.c.myjsoncolumn))`

But it says that the function need at least two parameters.

Comment: To merge you are after two documents](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_merge_preserve/). Are you after an aggregate of all the values of that column. Its possible to create a [MariaDB aggregate function the server side](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/stored-aggregate-functions/) for this.

Answer (score 1):

An example is to create the SQL function:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION json_merge_preserve_agg(j TINYTEXT) RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE r TEXT;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND return r;
  LOOP
    FETCH GROUP NEXT ROW;
    IF r IS NULL THEN
      SET r = j;
    ELSE
      SET r = JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(r, j);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END //
```

Some sample data:

```
create table j (t text);

insert into j values ('[1, 2]'),('[2, 4]');
```

Use the function to return results:

```
 select json_merge_preserve_agg(t) from j;
```

Using the function from sql alchemeny is like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140037/call-a-function-with-parameters-in-sqlalchemy):

```
 from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

 result = conn.execute(select(func.json_merge_preserve_agg(db.mytable.c.myjsoncolum)))
```

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/51HQzseY)

ref: [aggregate functions of MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/stored-aggregate-functions/)

Note: MariaDB-10.3+ only, MySQL doesn't have aggregate (non-UDF) functions.

Comment: thanks- I used same logic but implemented with in sqlalchemy and python.

Comment: Thought you might. I'm curious of a speed comparison between the two if you have time. And which MariaDB version as a reference point.

Comment: I posted my solution. I am sure your answer might be more perfomant but, I have mysql in production and mariadb in development mode. I will try to make some measurements like you asked.

Comment: Just a suggestion, I'd keep your development and production on the same version and implemenation. :-)

Comment: You are right. It is a relic from the past. I should correct it.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the sql logic mentioned in danblack's  answer and implemented directly in python.

```py
    conn = engine.connect()
    qry_1 = select(db.mytable.c.myjsoncolumn).where(mycondition)
    res = conn.execute(qry_1).fetchall()
    qry_2 = select(func.json_merge_preserve('
                {}', 
               *[json.dumps(r['myjsoncolumn']) for r in res]
            ))
    res_2 = conn.execute(qry_2).fetchone()[0]
    # res_2 is the answer
```

I am not sure of the performance implications of this solution.